# Send Range of Cells to Multiple Recipients

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this, so please bear with me. I am trying to send a specified range of cells to different contacts on a loop. So far, this is operational for 1 contact per email. Is there a way to modify this code to send the email to multiple individuals from a spreadsheet along with having multiple individuals from the same sheet on cc?

Please note, I pieced together much of the below code from Ron Debruin's site

```
Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_1()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Ash As Worksheet
    Dim Cws As Worksheet
    Dim Rcount As Long
    Dim Rnum As Long
    Dim FilterRange As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Integer
    Dim mailAddress As String
    Dim StrBody As String



    On Error GoTo cleanup
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
    Set Ash = ActiveSheet

    'Set filter range and filter column (Column with names)
    Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A1:H" & Ash.Rows.Count)
    FieldNum = 1    'Filter column = A because the filter range start in A

    'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
    Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
    FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
            CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

    'Count of the unique values + the header cell
    Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

    'If there are unique values start the loop
    If Rcount >= 2 Then
        For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

            'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
            FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                                   Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

            'Look for the mail address in the MailInfo worksheet
            mailAddress = ""
            On Error Resume Next
            mailAddress = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                          VLookup(Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value, _
                                Worksheets("Mailinfo").Range("A1:C" & _
                                Worksheets("Mailinfo").Rows.Count), 2, False)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If mailAddress <> "" Then
                With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      On Error GoTo 0
                End With

                Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

  StrBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Dear team, <br><br>" & _
              "Please see below for this week's data queries.<br><br>"

                On Error Resume Next
                With OutMail
                    .display
                    .To = mailAddress
                    .bcc = "emily_thomas@virtualscopics.com"
                    .Subject = "CA209-915 BioTel Research Weekly Queries"
                    .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & .HTMLBody
                    .Attachments.Add ("\\corp.virtualscopics.com\org\Dept\Project Management\Team\Projects\33320 - BMS - CA209-915\Signed Documents\Site Documents\All Approved Site Docs and Approval Forms\33320_ct_mri_subject_data_transmittal_form_v1.1.pdf")
                    .display  'Or use Send
                End With
                On Error GoTo 0

                Set OutMail = Nothing
                Set OutApp = Nothing
            End If

            'Close AutoFilter
            Ash.AutoFilterMode = False

        Next Rnum
    End If

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Cws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         FileName:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile
    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: You want an outer loop which sets the mailaddress and picks up an filtering that needs to happen and passes the mail address ( and cc if varies) to a function call that generates and sends the e-mail. You might want to further divide tasks between subs and functions so each does pretty much one thing. You also don’t need .Display twice. Keep the last one if you want to see but not send.

Comment: Or if sending the same info to multiple people then concatenate the addresses (;) and pass that string as the mailaddress